# spawn_model fails in ROS groovy (Gazebo 1.3.0)

Tags: gazebo-1.3, groovy

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,
A few days ago I switched from fuerte to groovy. The shipped gazebo version at this time was 1.2.5 . Scince everything was working fine (simulating robots, spawning models, etc.) I decided to install groovy on 2 other machines. On those machines simulator gazebo has version 1.3.0   and it is not possible to spawn any models via "rosrun gazebo spawn_model ...".
When using files with SDF version 1.3 I always get the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1359494067.230314246]: GazeboRosApiPlugin SpawnModel Failure: input xml format not recognized
```

I've made some experiments with really simple models and even older sdf versions. Nothing seems to work here.
Any suggestions why this not working anymore?

Best regards,

Tobi

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1121/spawn_model-fails-in-ros-groovy-(gazebo-1.3.0)/) by [Tobi_von_T](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/180/tobi_von_t/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-01-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

How to spawn a model:

```
$ gzfactory spawn -f <sdf_file>
```

There are bunch of other options:

```
$ gzfactory -h
```

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I get the feeling that most of the command line tools for spawning models are broken.  The preferred way to launch SDFs is by putting models in the appropriate directory. Then they appear in the list of insertable models in Gazebo. The instructions are [here.](http://gazebosim.org/user_guide/started__models__database.html)

---

Originally posted by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) with karma: 175 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1